# A matricial process to assign different values to elements of a diagonal matrix

Tags: matrices

Consider having vector

$$v = \begin{pmatrix}
v_1\\
v_2\\
\vdots\\
v_n
\end{pmatrix}$$

Consider the final result:

$$
V = 
\begin{pmatrix}
v_1 & 0 & \dots & 0\\
0 & v_2 & \dots & 0\\
\vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots\\
0 & 0 & \dots & v_n\\
\end{pmatrix}
$$

How to get matrix $V$ operating on $v$ with matricial operations?

Thanks

Comment: $\sum_i v^Te_i\cdot e_ie_i^T$ with the $i$-th standard basis vector denoted by $e_i$.

Comment: What are 'matricial operations'?

Comment: I mean just products and sums...

Answer (score 1):

You can see that the basis vectors must be involved in this conversion, because the result depends on the basis we use. For example, $v=(1,\dots,1)^T$ will produce the identity matrix, but not if we operate in a different basis. This is why there cannot be a natural coordinate-free transformation of $v$ into $V$.

In the formula given by *martini*, $V=\sum_{i=1}^n (v^T e_i)(e_ie_i^T)$, the product $e_ie_i^T$ is the matrix with $(i,i)$ entry $1$ and other entries $0$. Multiplication by the scalar  $v^T e_i = v_i$ turns $1$ into $v_i$. Summation over $i$ completes the construction.

By the way,  Matlab has built-in `diag(v)` for this purpose.